# Setting default html lang tag in struts

Tags: struts-1

I need to add the `<html lang='en'>` tag to all of my pages.

I can go and modify all of the tags on each page (as below), but is there a way to configure this to be the default?

```
<html xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" 
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" xmlns:s="/struts-tags"
lang="true">
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with S2, it's an HTML question, no?

Comment: You can't use this code for S2 tags or JSTL, can you?

Comment: I was looking at the docs here: https://people.apache.org/~germuska/struts-taglib/docs/tlddoc/html/html.html but this might refer to Struts 1? I might just punt this off to another person.